# Is there a way to get download all the statistics on events at once from Flurry?

Tags: flurry

We are bumping into limitations with Flurry. We use events and parameters to track some game play info (like number of KO/map) but 1/ the limit of 15 parameters per event is a problem and 2/ the visualisation is not good (for instance Ko/map is shown by map so we have to open each event one after another).

We are trying to build a better visualisation with excel using the CSV files provided by Flurry, but then again we need to download the 50+ CSV files and it's really not convenient.

Is there a way to get all the information in one CSV or to get the information another way?

As a side note Flurry support is not answering any of our emails. :(

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking out playtomic instead. Sounds like it might match your problem better.
They have an API to access your data. So you should be able to access it realtime.
You might also want to check out www.parse.com

Comment: Playtomic has shut down.